# Conversion from base 11 to 10 c++

Tags: c++, string

This code can convert from base 11 to base 10:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main ()
{
    string str;
    cout <<"CONVERSION\n\n";
    cout <<"Base 11 to Decimal\n";
    cout << "Base 11: ";
    getline (std::cin,str);
    unsigned long ul = std::stoul (str,nullptr,11);
    cout << "Decimal: " << ul << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

But when i enter B-Z that is not included to base 11, the program stops, what i want to happen is like this

[image]

if the user enters invalid variables, the program should say "Invalid Input". please help

Comment: Check the result of the conversion for errors? Seriously, how should the program display "Invalid Input" if there is no code for that?

Comment: im just a newbie and our professor didn't tought us about this conversion, we ended up on switch code only.

Comment: Suggestion: do it the way your professor wants, it is important stuff you should learn.

Comment: You should learn how to use refererence documentation... Try http://cppreference.com and look up how *stoul* can report errors.

Comment: You haven't shown us the code that does what you display in your question. Nobody can help you fix code you haven't shown us.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`std::string::find_first_not_of`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find_first_not_of)

```
...
getline (std::cin,str);
const auto bad_loc = str.find_first_not_of("0123456789aA");
if(bad_loc != std::string::npos) {
  throw "bad input"; // or whatever handling
}
unsigned long ul = std::stoul (str,nullptr,11);
...
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, it gets me error when trying your code, can you edit my code for me ? im a beginner and our professor didn't teach us this coding

Comment: @JetMortolaJoseph why would your professor expect you to be able to write code you haven't been taught how to write? That makes no sense.

Comment: I have no idea, he said that this will be our project and we can make this with youtube, but neither youtube cant help me :( would be my pleasure if you can

Comment: Im taking civil engineering and our subject is prog language 1

Comment: @JetMortolaJoseph I recommend you go back to your professor and ask him to clarify how you should complete this assignment. We're not a free homework completion site.

Comment: nevermind, thanks for your help tho, he wont tell me how no matter what.

Comment: @JetMortolaJoseph Instead of throw you may print error. See the code working [here](http://ideone.com/vyiy8a).